# Assigning values with ternary operator in ERB configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ternary-operator

There is a couple of erb ternary related questions here, but they asked about a bit different use cases compared to the one I have.

So, there is a configuration file that for example looks like this:

```
<% if node['node_environment'] == 'production' %>
envProp.serverUrl=//prod.server.com
<% else %>
envProp.serverUrl=//other.server.com
<% end %>
```

I would like to populate the envProp.serverUrl in a ternary style the in Java would look like:

```
envProp.serverUrl = if(node("node_enviroment")
.equals("production) ? "//prod.server.com" : "//other.server.com"
```

How should it be done in the .erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very similar to your Java example.

```
envProp.serverUrl=<%= note['note_environment'] == 'production' ? '//prod.server.com' : '//other.server.com' %>
```